# How to enforce null checking for objects multiple layers deep?

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux-saga

I am using redux sagas to get data asynchronously from multiple endpoints through a common interface:

```
export interface ResponseInfo {
    data?: any;
    status: number;
    headers?: any;
    subCode?: string;
}
```

I want to enforce null checking on the data object (which has to be of type any) so that when another developer attempts to write

`if(response.data.pizza.toppings){}`

it will fail to compile unless he or she adds null checking,

```
if(response.data && response.data.pizza && response.data.pizza.toppings){

}
```

We are using typescript but `--strictNullChecks` will not flag the above line without null checking.  Is this what [no-unsafe-any](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-unsafe-any/) is for in tslint?  Is there a way to get typescript to do this check on it's own?

Comment: You can check type guards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can define such an object using an interface with an index signature:

```
export interface ResponseInfo {
    data?: RecursiveObject;
    status: number;
    headers?: any;
    subCode?: string;
}

interface RecursiveObject {
    [s: string]: RecursiveObject | undefined
}

// Usage 

declare let response : ResponseInfo
if(response.data.pizza.toppings){ // Object is possibly 'undefined'

}

if(response.data.pizza){ // Object is possibly 'undefined'

}
```

The one problem is `response.data.pizza.toppings` is a `RecursiveObject` which is not very useful. To get around this (and to also be extra safe) we can use a custom type guard to narrow the type of the final result to something useful. (Note a regular type guard will not work because `RecursiveObject` is unrelated to string and a simple guard such as `typeof response.data.pizza.toppings === 'string'` will actually narrow to `never`)

```
function isString(o: RecursiveObject|string ): o is string {
    return typeof o === "string"
}

declare let response : ResponseInfo
if(response.data && response.data.pizza && response.data.pizza.toppings
    && isString(response.data.pizza.toppings) ){
    let s : string = response.data.pizza.toppings;

}
```

A bit verbose, but might be useful.